# Flutter Geolocator PositionStream stops working in android studio emulator

Tags: flutter, riverpod, geolocator

Until yesterday the Geolocator positionStream was working just fine.
I can't figure out why the stream does not produce any values even when I use the Extended Controls Tool to change the location of the device.

Here the riverpod position stream provider

```
@riverpod
Stream<Position> positionStream(
  PositionStreamRef ref,
) async* {
  final locationService = ref.watch(locationServiceProvider);

  yield* locationService.geolocator.getPositionStream(
    locationSettings: locationService.getLocationSettings(),
  );
}
```

And the location service has this method for the settings.

```
LocationSettings getLocationSettings() {
if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
  return AndroidSettings(
      distanceFilter: 50,
      //(Optional) Set foreground notification config to keep the app alive
      //when going to the background
      foregroundNotificationConfig: const ForegroundNotificationConfig(
        notificationTitle: "Running in Background",
        notificationText:
            "Example app will continue to receive your location even when you aren't using it",
        notificationIcon: AndroidResource(name: 'notification_icon'),
      ));
} else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS) {
  return AppleSettings(
    accuracy: LocationAccuracy.best,
    distanceFilter: AppLocationSettings.locationChangeDistance,
    activityType: ActivityType.automotiveNavigation,
    pauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically: true,
    // Only set to true if our app will be started up in the background.
    showBackgroundLocationIndicator: true,
  );
} else {
  return const LocationSettings(
    accuracy: LocationAccuracy.best,
    distanceFilter: 50,
  );
}
}
```

I am using another provider to listen to the positionStreamProvider:

```
@riverpod
CameraPosition 
myLocationCameraPosition(MyLocationCameraPositionRef ref) {
  final myLocation =
      ref.watch(positionStreamProvider.select((value) => 
value.valueOrNull));

  return CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(
      myLocation?.latitude ?? defaultLatLng.latitude,
      myLocation?.longitude ?? defaultLatLng.longitude,
    ),
    zoom: defaultMapZoom,
  );
}
```

This is the provider which is not updating anymore.
It is just annoying to spend hours just to figure out why it just stops working.
Maybe I am missing something.

I start the provider by doing the following in one of the screens of the app.

```
final locationAsync = ref.watch(
  positionStreamProvider.select((value) => value.whenData((value) => true)),
);
```

Basically I would use the Extended Controls Tool of the emulator to change the location and the positionStrean would yield a new value. But that is not happening anymore. The location is change on the map, but nothing happens with positionStream.
I can't see any error logs.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem without understanding why the fix is working.

I have changed from:

```
@riverpod
CameraPosition myLocationCameraPosition(MyLocationCameraPositionRef ref) 
{
  final myLocation =
      ref.watch(positionStreamProvider.select((value) => 
value.valueOrNull));

  return CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(
      myLocation?.latitude ?? defaultLatLng.latitude,
      myLocation?.longitude ?? defaultLatLng.longitude,
    ),
    zoom: defaultMapZoom,
  );
}
```

to

```
@riverpod
CameraPosition myLocationCameraPosition(MyLocationCameraPositionRef ref) 
{
  final myLocation = ref.watch(positionStreamProvider).valueOrNull;

  return CameraPosition(
   target: LatLng(
      myLocation?.latitude ?? defaultLatLng.latitude,
      myLocation?.longitude ?? defaultLatLng.longitude,
    ),
    zoom: defaultMapZoom,
  );
}
```

I thought the first version should be the recommended one. It used to work before. But for some reason it doesn't anymore.
Also I can't really see why the second one is working instead.